# How to use ASP.NET Session State in an HttpHandler?

Tags: httphandler, session-state

I have an HttpHandler that is run on a client page (cross domain, not on our IIS server, etc) and when they click on our embedded link it fires off the Handler on our server.  So far everything is working normally.

I am now trying to use the System.Web.HttpContext.Session object but it is null.  I am thinking it is null because we don't have a session until our HttpHandler is invoked?  And multiple calls to the handler will create a new session per call?  If this is the case did MS just disable the Session object when calling into a HttpHandler?  Can anyone confirm this?

If this is the case, what do you do to maintain state between calls?  Some sort of SQL based data object?  A file?

TIA

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Have your HttpHandler implement the **IRequiresSessionState** interface.  It will enable session state use. 
IRequiresSessionState can be found in the `System.Web.SessionState` namespace.

Comment: @Michael wouldn't of thought of that in a million years 
thanks :)

Comment: Implementing worked for me:
Public Class BasicHandler
    Implements IHttpHandler
    Implements IRequiresSessionState

Answer (score 31):

I think you have to implement the empty interface [IReadOnlySessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.ireadonlysessionstate.aspx), so the context will be loaded.

**edit to add:**

According to Michael Morton's answer, you can also **implement** [IRequiresSessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate.aspx), which will give you write access also to the Session object

Comment: For many httphandler uses IReadOnlySessionState is best, at least when one is only checking session state not saving it, but the main reason this is the better answer is because an HttpHandler implements IReadOnlySessionState or IRequiresSessionState rather than inherits (classes can inherit only from other classes).

Comment: We found IReadOnlySessionState was substantially faster.

Answer (score 11):

```
using System; 
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;
public class DownloadHandler : IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState
{
   public bool IsReusable { get { return true; } }

   public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   {
       context.Response.Write(context.Session["kmx"]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score -10):

try using the current context...

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session
```

Comment: doesn't work, unless he implements one of the both marker interfaces

Comment: Session will be null without IRequiresSessionState /  IReadOnlySessionState

Comment: My bad... was thinking of HttpModules.

Comment: The OP said: **I am now trying to use the System.Web.HttpContext.Session object but it is null.**